# Check the textbox contains any characters and numbers

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I wanted to make where the text in the textbox entered by user, have to contains characters followed by numbers. Example: A1001. I already found a solution using the Regex and show an error message box if the textbox not contains characters followed by number, but once I entered the text "A1" in the textbox, the error message box still appear.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(this.textBox1.Text, @"(a-zA-Z)"))
            {
                SystemManager.ShowMessageBox("Please enter the characters followed by the numbers for the product code. \nExample: A1001", "Information", 2);
            }

            else if (!Regex.IsMatch(this.textBox1.Text, @"(0-9)"))
            {
                SystemManager.ShowMessageBox("Please enter the characters followed by the numbers for the product code. \nExample: A1001", "Information", 2);
            }
        }
```

Your answer very much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Combine the 2 regex's into 1.

[a-zA-Z0-9]*

Comment: What is a `character` for you? Give some sample strings that must match and some that mustn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z]+\d+$
```

Try this.This one regex will validate your conditions.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/25

Comment: Your answer was worked for me and the bug as mention above "`AA1`" was worked also. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use one regex for the whole expression:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(this.textBox1.Text, @"^[a-zA-z][0-9]+$"))
{
  SystemManager.ShowMessageBox("Please enter the characters followed by the numbers for the product code. \nExample: A1001", "Information", 2);
}
```

This will match for a string having one character followed by one or more digits. If you want to allow more than one character you have to use `[a-zA-z]+`.

As I assume that you want to enter only the product code in this field I also added the ^ for start and $ for end of the string.

Comment: Found a bug as you said, it will not match when there are two characters followed by the numbers. `AA1`

Comment: @vks: Your answer was worked for me and the bug as mention above "`AA1`" was worked also. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In forms you can also use the MaskedTextbox, use this control and set the Mask property to:

```
L0000
```

This way you force the user to enter one letter(L) and 4 numbers(0000). Of course you can customize it the way you want.

For example LLL-000 will give you 3 letters followed by an indent and 3 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems like bit confusing.
Please try this inside the button click

```
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(this.MyTextBox.Text, @"[A-C][0-9]{4}"))
        {
            SystemManager.ShowMessageBox("Please enter the characters followed by the numbers for the product code. \nExample: A1001", "Information", 2);
        }
```